# Failed at the grpc@1.7.2 install script

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I am trying to deploy a build a Docker image containing a react app. I am trying to use `node:8-alpine` as my base image. However, I am running into this error during the `npm` install layer. I tried using the standard `node` base image and every thing works fine, but the file size is 1GB so I'd really like to use alpine.

I am running `macOS 10.12.6` `node 8.7.0`

```
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-
gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --
module=/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-
linux-
x64-musl/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --
module_path=/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-
linux-x64-musl' (1)
npm info lifecycle grpc@1.7.2~install: Failed to exec install script
npm WARN sign-in-app@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 
(node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.7.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --
library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.7.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-12-06T18_26_09_926Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same issue this morning. Looks like the precompiled grpc1.7.2 hasn't been uploaded for musl based distributions (alpine is musl vs glibc)

For the short term, to get your build going again, and until they upload the precompiled versions, try adding this to your dockerfile

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache python make g++
```

python, make and g++ basically allow node-gyp to compile from source rather than relying on the precompiled versions